# How to access a row which is dynamically created in GOHTML template?

Tags: go, modal-dialog, go-html-template

In my GOHTML file, I am dynamically creating table rows from the results using range. Further, I want to access each row for operations like edit or delete. For example: Click on a row should open a modal with its values. But, with my current implementation the modal is appearing only on the first row. Click doesn't work on rest of the rows.

**Table :**

```
<table>
{{range .Bdata}}

    <tr class="buy" id="trx_buy"> 
          <td>{{.Sname}}</td> 
          <td align="center">{{.Uprice}} </td> 
          <td align="center">{{.Qty}} </td>
          <td align="center">{{.Bfee}}</td>
          <td align="center">{{.Tprice}}</td>
          <td align="center">{{.Fdate}}</td>
     </tr> 
        {{end}}
      </table>
```

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>{{.Sname}}, {{.Uprice}} </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Script to handle onclick :**

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

var tr_buy = document.getElementById("trx_buy");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

tr_buy.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in `var tr_buy = document.getElementById("trx_buy");`. This will only give you the first matching element. You can use `document.getElementsByClassName` instead and add the onClick() listener to all the elements.